# PHP - get string between position and next occurrence of characters

Tags: php

For example, my string is: `DELIMxxxyyyzzzaaabbbcc,DELIMaaabbcccxxxyyyzzz,DELIMzzzyyyxxxaaabbbccc,DELIMyyyaaabbb,`

You can see this data is organised in delimited groups. I want to extract the second group (for example) where I'm given the position (in this case 24) and the next delimiter which I know to be "DELIM".

What combination of `substr` and `strpos` or others would I use to get this?

Comment: You mean you give any position in the string and get the next delimiter in the string?

Comment: The title of your question does not seem to match the content.

Comment: @Warren Could we solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strpos` to select the start and end position of your delimited group. Then you can use `substr` to get the delimeted group by selecting the string between those two positions.

```
$offset = 4;

$start = strpos($mystring, 'DELIM', $offset); //select start point

$end = strpos($mystring, 'DELIM', $start+5); //select end point by selecting next delimiter

$substr = substr($mystring, $start, $end-$start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos with offset

```
$mystring = 'DELIMxxxyyyzzzaaabbbcc,DELIMaaabbcccxxxyyyzzz,DELIMzzzyyyxxxaaabbbccc,DELIMyyyaaabbb,'
$pos = strpos($mystring, 'DELIM', 24+1 + strlen('DELIM'));

$myPart = substr($mystring, 24, $pos);
```

Comment: That will extract only part of the second group. The title and content of the question seem to contradict :-)

Comment: I have update the answer  ... anyway the concept remain the same  .. offset and legnth

Comment: I actually meant at the start, you won't get the characters before position 24 / xx that might be part of the second (in this case...) group.

Comment: @warren show me the actual result from my code and your expected .. result .

Comment: Based on the comment below the question, the position can be any place in the group and the OP wants to extract the whole group, from beginning to end. So if the position happens to be at the first `x`, it seems the OP wants the whole `DELIMaaabbcccxxxyyyzzz,` (with / without delimiter, that's not important...) and not `xxyyyzzz,`. As far as I can tell...